# Pandas groupby and substract depending on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the below data set

```
id name mode value
1   x    buy  20
1   x    sell 15
2   y    sell 10
3   z    buy  10
```

I want to find the net transaction done by a name for a single it so the above case the output should be

```
id name value
1   x    5
2   y    -10
3   z    10
```

How can this be done. I tried group_by and then apply but it is not working.
Tried to split the frames based on **mode** by it fails for y&z let me know how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first change the value with mode after `map` , then `groupby`

```
s=df.assign(value=df.value.mul(df['mode'].map({'buy':1,'sell':-1}))).\
          groupby(['id','name'],as_index=False).sum()
   id name  value
0   1    x      5
1   2    y    -10
2   3    z     10
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, We can use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
new_df = (df.assign(value = df['value'].where(df['mode'].eq('buy'), -df['value']))
            .groupby(['id', 'name'],as_index=False)['value'].sum())
print(new_df)

   id name  value
0   1    x      5
1   2    y    -10
2   3    z     10
```

Or:

```
new_df = (df.groupby(['id','name','mode'])['value'].sum()
            .unstack('mode',fill_value=0)
           .assign(value=lambda x: x.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]))
print(new_df)

mode     buy  sell  value
id name                  
1  x      20    15   -5.0
2  y       0    10   10.0
3  z      10     0  -10.0
```

If you don't want `buy` and `sell` columns

```
new_df = new_df.drop(columns=['buy', 'sell'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the sell value by -1 and then `groupby`:

```
df['value'] = np.where(df['mode']=='sell', df['value']*-1, df['value'])
df = df.groupby(by=['id', 'name'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df)

   id name  value
0   1    x      5
1   2    y    -10
2   3    z     10
```